# Issues at deploying site

Tags: next.js13, next-auth

> [next-auth][error][OAUTH_CALLBACK_ERROR]
> https://next-auth.js.org/errors#oauth_callback_error client_secret_basic client authentication method requires a client_secret {
> error: TypeError: client_secret_basic client authentication method requires a client_secret
> at Y.h (/var/task/.next/server/app/api/auth/[...nextauth]/route.js:39:27867)
> at Y.f (/var/task/.next/server/app/api/auth/[...nextauth]/route.js:39:28274)
> at Y.grant (/var/task/.next/server/app/api/auth/[...nextauth]/route.js:39:14948)
> at Y.callback (/var/task/.next/server/app/api/auth/[...nextauth]/route.js:39:2824)
> at l (/var/task/.next/server/app/api/auth/[...nextauth]/route.js:6:120490)
> at async Object.c (/var/task/.next/server/app/api/auth/[...nextauth]/route.js:30:780)
> at async _ (/var/task/.next/server/app/api/auth/[...nextauth]/route.js:6:102821)
> at async a (/var/task/.next/server/app/api/auth/[...nextauth]/route.js:30:18205)
> at async e.length.t (/var/task/.next/server/app/api/auth/[...nextauth]/route.js:30:18818)
> at async /var/task/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-route.runtime.prod.js:6:42484 {
> name: 'OAuthCallbackError',
> code: undefined
> },
> providerId: 'descope',
> message: 'client_secret_basic client authentication method requires a client_secret'
> }

I have tried to every possible way known but still not getting the solution can someone help me out with this

Comment: Please provide some more information. What is the code or command that is causing this error?
Also please explain in more detail what you have already tried.

Comment: Please have a look at [ask]. How do you expect us to help you when you only dump an error?